# why do i receive this error?

Tags: pde, python, matplotlib

I want to plot the 100,200 and 400 iterations of this function of non homogeneous parabolic pde

```
def solver(L, Nx, Nt, T, theta=0.5):
    

    x = np.linspace(-L,L, Nx+1)   # mesh points in space
    dx = (L-(-L))/(Nx-1)
    dt = 1/Nt

    Nt = int(round(T/float(dt)))
    t = np.linspace(0, T, Nt+1)   # mesh points in time

    h = (L-(-L))/(Nx+1)
    t = T / Nt
    m = t/h**2
    #print("m =", round(m,2))

    u   = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # solution array at t[n+1]
    u_n = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # solution at t[n]
    a   = np.zeros(Nx+1) + (1+x**2)
    c   = np.ones(Nx+1) * -1

    Dl = 0.5*theta
    Dr = 0.5*(1-theta)

   
    diagonal = np.zeros(Nx+1)
    lower    = np.zeros(Nx)
    upper    = np.zeros(Nx)
    b        = np.zeros(Nx+1)

 
    diagonal[1:-1] = 1 + Dl*(a[2:] + 2*a[1:-1] + a[:-2])
    lower[:-1] = -Dl*(a[1:-1] + a[:-2])
    upper[1:]  = -Dl*(a[2:] + a[1:-1])
    
    
    diagonal[0] = 1
    upper[0] = 0
    diagonal[Nx] = 1
    lower[-1] = 0

    A = scipy.sparse.diags(
        diagonals=[diagonal, lower, upper],
        offsets=[0, -1, 1],
        shape=(Nx+1, Nx+1),
        format='csr')
    
    def I(x):
        return(np.sin(np.pi*x))

   
    for i in range(0,Nx+1):
        u_n[i] = I(x[i])

   

    # Time loop
    for n in range(0, Nt):
        b[1:-1] = u_n[1:-1] + Dr*(
            (a[2:] + a[1:-1])*(u_n[2:] - u_n[1:-1]) -
            (a[1:-1] + a[0:-2])*(u_n[1:-1] - u_n[:-2])) + dt*theta*c[1:-1] + dt*(1-theta)*c[1:-1]
        
        # Boundary conditions
        b[0]  = 0
        b[-1] = 0
        # Solve
        u[:] = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b)

        u_n,u = u, u_n 
    
        plt.plot(u[:,100])
```

I receive this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-41c85be859a3> in <module>
----> 1 Back = solver(L=1, Nx=39, Nt=400, T=1, theta=1)

<ipython-input-90-ef7886a9d8f0> in solver(L, Nx, Nt, T, theta)
     68         u_n,u = u, u_n
     69 
---> 70         plt.plot(u[:,100])
     71 

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: U a vector. Just use `plt.plot(u)` I guess.

Comment: it plots all the iterations if do this

Comment: No, as far as I understand u is a vector that has the same dimension as your number of mesh points. U is then the value of your field at time t.

Comment: The same I thought.But You can run it.You will see.

Comment: For the question at hand: Laurent90 is of course right -- `u` is a vector, and `u[:,100]` correctly points out that you can't subscript it with *two* indices. The syntax you use would extract the 100'th column from a matrix, but it is not the right syntax for extracting a subset of a vector.

Comment: I don't know what you *want* to do, and it doesn't matter for the error either: Whatever it is that you want to do can not be achieved with this syntax.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth and Laurent90 I want to plot the 100 200 and 400 nsteps of the Backward Euler and Crank Nicolson method.I understand that u is a vector.But this code I have found in the Langtangen book for Finite Differences Method for non homogeneous pde.

Comment: [This is the code I used](https://github.com/hplgit/fdm-book/blob/master/src/diffu/diffu1D_vc.py) this one

Comment: Well then H-P was wrong in the book. (It's sad that he can't fix it any more :-( )

Comment: I'll add that the answers you get are due to the subject line and the question you posted: "Why do I get this error?" The answers all correctly point out why. You didn't ask how to achieve what you wanted to do, so the comments didn't answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I've taken a closer look a the code. One first advice that I could give you is to try to understand how the code works. It is very easy to understand that the for-loop is a time loop, i.e. the system is advanced forward one time step at each iteration of the loop. The time marching equation uses a theta-scheme for the time discretization (theta=0.5 --> Crank-Nicolson scheme), and the resulting linear system is solved with the sparse linear solver from Scipy.
The resolution of this linear system gives the vector $u$ of discrete temperatures (or the actual physical value whose evolution you're computing) on every mesh point. The way you code is written, it store the past values of u. SO either you save (say, in a list for example) or you just use the value of $u$ on the fly when you want to.

By the way, the method to update $Nt$ was wrong, as well as the method to compute $dt$, so I've modified your code accordingly.

Also, try to post a code that is directly usable ;)
I had to import some modules, and also setup the call to the `solver` function to make it work.

Here is the final result with the call `solver(L=1, Nx=30, Nt=400, T=200., theta=1)` (so 30 elements):

[image]

By the way, something seems wrong with the model, as it does not converge in space. For example, with 3000 points instead of 30 I get the next figure. And the situation only worsens as the number of points $N_x$ is increased... I don't know what is is you are modelling, but that should be checked. I also see that the mesh spacing `dx` is not used in your code, which seems rather surprising.

[image]

And the code is:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.sparse.linalg

def solver(L, Nx, Nt, T, theta=0.5):
    x = np.linspace(-L,L, Nx+1)   # mesh points in space
    dx = (L-(-L))/(Nx-1)
       
    t = np.linspace(0, T, Nt+1)   # mesh points in time
    dt = t[1]-t[0]

    h = (L-(-L))/(Nx+1)

    u   = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # solution array at t[n+1]
    u_n = np.zeros(Nx+1)   # solution at t[n]
    a   = np.zeros(Nx+1) + (1+x**2)
    c   = np.ones(Nx+1) * -1

    Dl = 0.5*theta
    Dr = 0.5*(1-theta)
   
    diagonal = np.zeros(Nx+1)
    lower    = np.zeros(Nx)
    upper    = np.zeros(Nx)
    b        = np.zeros(Nx+1)
 
    diagonal[1:-1] = 1 + Dl*(a[2:] + 2*a[1:-1] + a[:-2])
    lower[:-1] = -Dl*(a[1:-1] + a[:-2])
    upper[1:]  = -Dl*(a[2:] + a[1:-1])
    
    diagonal[0] = 1
    upper[0] = 0
    diagonal[Nx] = 1
    lower[-1] = 0

    A = scipy.sparse.diags(
        diagonals=[diagonal, lower, upper],
        offsets=[0, -1, 1],
        shape=(Nx+1, Nx+1),
        format='csr')
    
    def I(x):
        return(np.sin(np.pi*x))

    u_n[:Nx+1] = I(x[:Nx+1])
      
    # Time loop
    for n in range(0, Nt):
        print('iter {}/{}'.format(n,Nt))
        b[1:-1] = u_n[1:-1] + Dr*(
            (a[2:] + a[1:-1])*(u_n[2:] - u_n[1:-1]) -
            (a[1:-1] + a[0:-2])*(u_n[1:-1] - u_n[:-2])) + dt*theta*c[1:-1] + dt*(1-theta)*c[1:-1]
        
        # Boundary conditions
        b[0]  = 0
        b[-1] = 0
        # Solve
        u[:] = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b)

        u_n,u = u, u_n 
        
        if 0 :# One plot for every selected iteration
          if np.mod(n,100)==0: # every 100 iterations
            plt.figure()
            plt.plot(x,u)
            plt.grid()
            plt.xlabel('x')
            plt.ylabel('u')
            plt.title('Solution at iteration {}'.format(n))
            plt.show()
        else: # one common figure for all the plotted iterations
          if np.mod(n,75)==0: # every 100 iterations
            if n==0: # instantiate the figure
              plt.figure()
              plt.grid()
              plt.xlabel('x')
              plt.ylabel('u')
            # plot the current iteration
            plt.plot(x,u, label='t={:.2f}'.format(t[n]))
            
            
if __name__=='__main__':
  solver(L=1, Nx=3000, Nt=400, T=200., theta=1)
  plt.legend(loc='center left', ncol=2)
```

**EDIT:**
from looking at the original file you said you adapted (https://github.com/hplgit/fdm-book/blob/master/src/diffu/diffu1D_vc.py), t seems the definition of `Dl` and `Dr` does not make sense with regards to the discretisation of the diffusion operator. It should involve the diffusion coefficient and the mesh spacing, not the coefficient `theta` of the temporal scheme.

Comment: The problem that I try to solve is this:Consider the following inhomogeneous parabolic initial/boundary value problem: 
$$u_{t}(t,x) = (1+x^{2})u_{xx}(t,x)+u(t,x),$$ for $t \in [0,1]$ and $x \in [-1,1]$
$$u(0,x) = \sin(\pi x),$$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ initial condition 
$$u(t,-1)=u(t,1)=0,$$ $t \in [0,1]$ Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Construct a Backward Euler method with $N_{x} =39$ and $Nt=400$ (i.e$\mu=1$) and show the iterations $n=100,200,400.$

In addition construct a Crank Nicolson method  with $N_{x} =39$ and $Nt=20$ (i.e$\mu=1/h$) and show the iterations $n=5,10,20.$

Comment: This is fairly easy to do starting from the code you have. You need to compute the terms of the Jacobian `A` for your new system. If you don't see how to do that, start by trying to discretise the classical diffusion equation $u_t = D u_{xx}$, then add a variable diffusion ($D(u)$ or $D(x)$). Gradually increase the complexity of your model and make sure you understand each step, otherwise you might end up not understanding and not learning much from the exercise.

Comment: The code above does that.The  non constant coefficient $\alpha$ is being added in A and also the constant $c= -1$.

Comment: Then your problem is solved, right ?

Comment: for me yes.Also that you said " Gradually increase the complexity of your model " is also succedd

Comment: Ok, then please accept the answer so that the issue is resolved ;)

Comment: ok sir Laurent .